# Adding phone number to contact in flutter/dart

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, contacts

I'm building a selectable checkbox contact list in flutter but if a contact has only an email and no number, an error is thrown. I want to create a loop to add a number of '99999' to the contacts phone number if they don't have one. Please can someone guide me with an explanation of what I should change to make this work? I have had a go, but I am quite new to flutter so I'm not completely certain on syntax etc...

Here is the part of the code that I am trying to put the function into.

```
setMissingNo()async {
  Iterable<Contact> contactsToLoop = (await ContactsService.getContacts()).toList();
  contactsToLoop.forEach((Contact) { contactsToLoop = []..add(Item.fromMap({'label': 'work', 'value': 99999})); });
}

//fetch contacts from setMissingNo
  getAllContacts() async{
  Iterable<Contact> _contacts = (await ContactsService.getContacts()).toList(); 

setState(() {
  contacts = _contacts;
  }
  );
}
```

Here is my whole code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// TODO: make it ask for permissions otherwise the app crashes
import 'package:contacts_service/contacts_service.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
List<Contact> contacts = [];
List<Contact> contactsFiltered = [];
TextEditingController searchController = new TextEditingController();

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAllContacts();
    searchController.addListener(() => filterContacts());
  }

//remove the +'s and spaces from a phone number before its searched
 String flattenPhoneNumber(String phoneStr) {
    return phoneStr.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'^(\+)|\D'), (Match m) {
      return m[0] == "+" ? "+" : "";
    });
  }


//loop and set all contacts without numbers to 99999, pass new list to getAllContacts
setMissingNo()async {
  Iterable<Contact> contactsToLoop = (await ContactsService.getContacts()).toList();
  contactsToLoop.forEach((Contact) { contactsToLoop = []..add(Item.fromMap({'label': 'work', 'value': 99999})); });
}

//fetch contacts from setMissingNo
  getAllContacts() async{
  Iterable<Contact> _contacts = (await ContactsService.getContacts()).toList(); 

setState(() {
  contacts = _contacts;
  }
  );
}


//filtering contacts function to match search term
 filterContacts() {
    List<Contact> _contacts = [];
    _contacts.addAll(contacts);
    if (searchController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      _contacts.retainWhere((contact) {
        String searchTerm = searchController.text.toLowerCase();
        String searchTermFlatten = flattenPhoneNumber(searchTerm);
        String contactName = contact.displayName.toLowerCase();
        bool nameMatches = contactName.contains(searchTerm);
        if (nameMatches == true) {
          return true;
        }

        if (searchTermFlatten.isEmpty) {
          return false;
        }

        var phone = contact.phones.firstWhere((phn) {
          String phnFlattened = flattenPhoneNumber(phn.value);
          return phnFlattened.contains(searchTermFlatten);
        }, orElse: () => null);

        return phone != null;
      });

      setState(() {
        contactsFiltered = _contacts;
      });
    }
  }



final selectedContacts = Set<Contact>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isSearching = searchController.text.isNotEmpty;

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[

            AppBar(
              title: Text('Create Group'),
            ),

            Container(
              child: TextField(
                controller: searchController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Search Contacts',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: new BorderSide(
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                    )
                  ),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                  )
                ),
              ),
            ),

                 Expanded( child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: isSearching == true ? contactsFiltered.length : contacts.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    Contact contact = isSearching == true ? contactsFiltered[index] : contacts[index];
                    //TODO: make it so when you clear your search, all items appear again & when you search words it works
                    return CheckboxListTile(
                      title: Text(contact.displayName),
                      subtitle: Text(
                        contact.phones.elementAt(0).value
                        ),                      
                       value: selectedContacts.contains(contact),
                  onChanged: (bool value) { 
                    if (value) { 
                      selectedContacts.add(contact); 
                    } else {
                      selectedContacts.remove(contact); 
                    }
                    setState((){}); 

                               // TODO: add in function to add contact ID to a list
                           });
                          },
                          ),

                    /*new Expanded(
                    child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                     child: BottomNavigationBar(  
                currentIndex: _currentIndex,   

        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[

//TODO: create new contact functionality to add someone by name + email
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            title: Text('Add Contact'),
          ),

          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.create),
            title: Text('Create Group'),
          ),

        ],  
        onTap: (index) {
                  setState(() {
                  _currentIndex = index;
                  });     
                  }
        )
                    )
        )*/
        )
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating all contacts listed on the device might take a long time depending on the size of the device's contact list. Add that the task is being done on the UI thread. You may want to consider using [Isolate](https://medium.com/flutter-community/thread-and-isolate-with-flutter-30b9631137f3) for the task to move away the load from the UI thread. If you can also provide the errors that you're getting, it'll help us get a picture of the issue.

Another thing is, the way you're approaching the issue might be impractical. Is it really necessary to write a placeholder phone number to the contacts? The issue likely stems from trying to fetch the number from a contact but the Object returns null. Perhaps you may want to consider only updating the phone number when the contact is selected.